ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
I just want to run a simple database connection with hibernate, but it didn't work.
First time use Hibernate tool, and I placed the hibernate.cfg.xml under src/main/resources.
When I run this Java application contain:
SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").addAnnotatedClass(Users.class).buildSessionFactory();
It crashes with several exceptions:
Dec 23, 2024 6:58:20 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.15.Final
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 0 and column 0 in RESOURCE hibernate.cfg.xml. Message: null
...
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory

hibernate.cfg.xml:
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
 
        <!-- Connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
              <!-- Sample MySQL URL provided  -->  
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/rsryanl</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password">Password#00</property>
           
        <!-- Show SQL on console -->
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
 
        <!--Setting Session context model -->
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
 
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>

